How to efficiently fix this issue of wrong reference types?
I have a tex file
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,biblatex}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{S}
\usepackage[notcite,notref]{showkeys}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document} 

\chapter{Introduction} \label{chap}

\begin{assumption} \label{ass}
Let something hold.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
If \zcref{ass} holds, then
\begin{align}
B &= C , \label{thm:eq1} \\
X &= Y . \label{thm:eq4}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

From \zcref{thm} in \zcref{chap}, we have \eqref{thm:eq1}.

\end{document}


As you can see from above, the type of a reference is wrong. It is suggested from this answer that to fix the issue for environment assumption, I should use
\AddToHook{env/assumption/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=assumption}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{assumption}{Name-sg=Assumption}

I use many more environments in my thesis, so I have to manually adapt above snippet to each of them:
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\AddToHook{env/corollary/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=corollary}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{corollary}{Name-sg=Corollary}

\AddToHook{env/lemma/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=lemma}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{lemma}{Name-sg=Lemma}

\AddToHook{env/proposition/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=proposition}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{proposition}{Name-sg=Proposition}

\AddToHook{env/definition/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=definition}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{definition}{Name-sg=Definition}

\AddToHook{env/assumption/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=assumption}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{assumption}{Name-sg=Assumption}

\AddToHook{env/remark/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=remark}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{remark}{Name-sg=Remark}

\AddToHook{env/example/begin}{%
   \zcsetup{countertype={theorem=example}}}
\zcRefTypeSetup{example}{Name-sg=Example}

Is there a more efficient way to fix this issue of wrong reference type?

Yes, indeed, you need the countertype settings (see https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/issues/31 for some discussion). The link also contains a like convenience workaround, if you find that too cumbersome. But I don't think you need the Name-sg settings though, at least not most of them. If zref-clever already has the types defined, no need to do it again.

But, well, Ulrike is correct that it is needed for assumption, but I think all the other types you are using there are provided out of the box. For the list see the section "Reference types" in the manual.

Off-topic: Are you sure you want to set the S option globally? I'd understand setting cap, but S also sets capfirst...

@Thank you very much for your explanation. I have changed to \zcsetup{cap=true}. Also, I keep using the method you suggested, i.e., I don't redefine the command \mynewtheorem. Btw, could you add the type assumption to zref-clever? This environment shows up in almost every math paper...

Sorry, but the package already offers a more than fair set of types, and it is easy enough for users to define any others they might want.

As @gusbrs, the author of zref-clever, explained in the comments, \zcRefTypeSetup{...} is needed only for environment assumption because the other types are already support by default by zref-clever. One solution by @gusbrs, taken from here, is
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynewtheorem}{momo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#4}
    {\newtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]}
    {%
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {%
          \AddToHook{env/#1/begin}{\zcsetup{countertype={#2=#1}}}%
          \newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}%
        }
        {\newtheorem{#1}{#3}}%
    }%
}
\zcRefTypeSetup{assumption}{Name-sg=Assumption}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\mynewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\mynewtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\mynewtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\mynewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\mynewtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\mynewtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\mynewtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\mynewtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

However, above solution is not recommended by @gusbrs because it re-defines the internals of \newtheorem.

Even if I cooked this workaround (not a "solution"), I don't think it saves much, and I don't really recommend it...

@gusbrs I will leave your workaround here and let people chose :)
